# How to perform calculation in ASP.net Core where the calculation method is present in repository and need to call in controller for testing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I'm trying to perform a test using the Swagger API. Whenever I'm trying to input the timesheedid it gaves Error 500.

Here's the method

```
 public void ComputeProductivity(long timesheetId)
        {
            var timesheet = _artDBContext.Timesheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == timesheetId);
            if (timesheet != null)
            {
                var percentage = 100;
                var conversionValue = 60;
                var weekValue = 5;
                var totalWorkingHoursPerWeek = 7 / 365;
timesheet.TotalHoursWorked = Convert.ToDecimal(timesheet.TimesheetDateOut - timesheet.TimesheetDateIn);
                timesheet.ProductivityPerc = timesheet.TotalHoursWorked * percentage; 
                timesheet.ProductivityHr = timesheet.ProductivityMin / conversionValue;
                timesheet.ProductivityMin = timesheet.TotalHoursWorked * conversionValue;
                timesheet.FTERatio = (timesheet.TotalHoursWorked * weekValue) / (timesheet.TotalHoursWorked * totalWorkingHoursPerWeek );

                _artDBContext.Entry(timesheet).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _artDBContext.SaveChanges();          
            }
        }
```

and here's the error I'm getting

```
Undocumented
Error: response status is 500

Response body
Download
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ArchPortal.ART.Repository.Interface.ITimesheetRepository' while attempting to activate 'ArchPortal.ART.WebAPI.Controllers.TimesheetController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method34(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7154
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
:method: POST
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.hST4KUX5M6E=CfDJ8EXEmdxP_L9KuMlGxtZS0jlhrSBRZ4IrUDAEaYEvVQFB1cU3eYpFpnLe7UcI4uWnoBnl4laufEKpAfzGZxNi9FIRogfZUw748eKqm5FdObxE5qvuYse9jrb5UjVShfoanL8EajyKSdQ7sA0Hd7Kah1s,.AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8EXEmdxP%2FL9KuMlGxtZS0jkQY5wu3raX%2BfcdeJaexR64LKlxAZEevFg2yi2OgH33rxoNy09Kip%2B8k2%2BGALHBwComubsMgU86lD%2BXqDcvH3FV4WbSHu7Kk%2FAehnMuapbWdQPT76kLHcwtcaVtMw9JdnbxFi6gtxusJ%2BVX5zoav0%2BT
Origin: https://localhost:7154
Referer: https://localhost:7154/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 0
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Response headers
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Mon,09 Jan 2023 08:35:26 GMT
server: Kestrel

I'm trying to test if the computation works. And the data exist already in the database.

Comment: Please copy the error message as a text, not as an image - and ensure to include the entire message (currently the most important part of it is hidden under a scroll). Also, please show us the code of the method you're trying to run. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I already edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue means that your `ITimesheetRepository` interface is not registered in your DI container, so it can't be found when you're constructing your Controller.

To fix this, assuming you're using the default ASP.NET Core DI (as it seems from the error message) and assuming that your implementation class is called `TimesheetRepository`, you need to add one line to either your `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` depending on the ASP.NET Core version:

```
// I assume you have the following line somewhere in the same file:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); 
...
// Line to insert
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITimesheetRepository, TimesheetRepository>();
...
// and you should have the following lines _below_ the inserted one:
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.Run();
```

See also: [MSDN: Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'
 now I'm having this error. Cam from this line
timesheet.TotalHoursWorked = Convert.ToDecimal(timesheet.TimesheetDateOut - timesheet.TimesheetDateIn);

Comment: @eol Then you have successfully fixed the issue you've originally faced and are currently looking into something else. In your case you're using `Convert` unnecessarily, you need something like `timesheet.TotalHoursWorked = (timesheet.TimesheetDateOut - timesheet.TimesheetDateIn).TotalHours;` instead. Usually on SO you'd want to ask a separate question in such cases, see discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post

Comment: @eol One more comment after looking at your code: `_artDBContext.Entry(timesheet).State = EntityState.Modified;` - this line can be safely deleted. EF Core tracks the state of the entities you are getting from the database automatically and it will detect when you change the values of its properties even if you don't forcibly set the entities' state.